# Android AIDL Check Client Identity upon connecting

Tags: android, aidl

I have an app that acts as a service, and the second app needs to connect to it, so I'm using Android Interface Defenition Language (AIDL).
What is the best approach to limit the service accepting only that specific app? and in which method the identity of the client app should happen?

I know a client should have a copy of .aidl file, but I need more ways to check who is connecting to the service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are ways to check the identity of the app connecting to your aidl service.

1. **By checking the signing of the apps**:
   If you want only the apps that are signed by the same key as your app or [SystemApps](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/what-are-system-apps/) can connect to your service refer kotlin code is below :

Same Key Sign and IsSyetm app:

```
 private fun isSameKeySinged(packageManager: PackageManager, packageNameOfTheOtherApp: String): Boolean {
        return packageManager.checkSignatures(
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, packageNameOfTheOtherApp
        ) == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH
    }

    private fun isSystemApp(packageManager: PackageManager, packageNameOfTheOtherApp: String): Boolean {
        try {
            val applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(
                packageNameOfTheOtherApp, 0
            )
            if (applicationInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM != 0 || applicationInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP != 0) {
                return true
            }
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return false
    }
```

2. **By Checking the caller App**: You can retrieve the package name of the caller using getCalledId inside the methods which other app call:

`val callingApp = packageManager.getNameForUid(Binder.getCallingUid())`

Comment: In which method should I call the mentioned methods?

Comment: @ramtin2C You can create a class and put these methods. And if you satisfied with the answer please accept it.

Comment: The question is how we can restrict to serve requests only from some applications in the aidl server side. I think you misunderstood the question.